# HTML form on user inputs to a PDF file in a new browser tab

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, pdf.js

Hey guys I am trying to use pdf.js , but am still noob with it. I have HTML user Sign-up form where user can input their name, email, and password. I have a submit button, which when the user clicks, it SHOULD generate in a new tab a pdf file with the input fields and the user submissions.

My jQuery code so far does nothing:

```
$(function() {
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#printButton').click(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#main-container').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these scripts in the code

```
<script src="js/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdf.worker.js"></script>
```